# Django-rest-framework-jwt won't return JWToken for nonstaff accounts (django admin error?)

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, jwt

So I've created a register page that allows visitors to register an account on my website. These accounts have `no staff status` or `administrative privileges`.

I've also created a login page that takes the username and password and sends an ajax post request to an auth url. The url links to obtain_jwt_token (django-rest-framework-jwt's view) which checks the username and password and then returns a jwt token to the visitor's localstorage.

This is all fine and dandy, and it works well. **Only problem is... well it works only for administrator accounts.** *For some reason the accounts with no staff status aren't validated*.

Json Web Tokens aren't returned for these accounts.

Is this an issue with django.admin.auth? or is it an issue with drt-jwt?

Is drt-jwt using the django admin page to authenticate users? Because that's not what I want. I don't just want admins to be able to log in to my website.

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. My account api allowed bad passwords to fall through, so my users model wasn't able to log that password.